# convert simple list of numbers to JSON array

Tags: python, json, list

I have a list containing numbers:

```
[123, 32, 434]
```

I need to convert it to JSON format which looks like this:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 123}, {'a': 2, 'b': 32},{'a': 3, 'b': 434}]
```

so, I need to add a running index to the list and then convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) and list comprehensions

```
>>> lst = [123, 32, 434]
>>> data = [{'a': k, 'b': v} for k, v in enumerate(lst, 1)]
>>> data
[{'a': 1, 'b': 123}, {'a': 2, 'b': 32}, {'a': 3, 'b': 434}]
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, i did some like this. May be its help full for you.

```
a = [2, 7, 55, 92]
l = []
for n in enumerate(a):
    l.append({"a":n[0]+1, "b":n[1]})
print l
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 7}, {'a': 3, 'b': 55}, {'a': 4, 'b': 92}]
```